# Different conventions between Fourier Transform and Characteristic Function

Tags: mathematics, probability, fourier

While it is clear that there are several conventions for Fourier transforms of intragrable functions on $\mathbb{R}$, I don't think I have ever seen anything different from the three following conventions
$$
\hat{f}(\xi)    =                        \int f(x) e^{-i 2 \pi \xi x} dx \\
\hat{f}(\omega) =                        \int f(x) e^{-i \omega x} dx    \\
\hat{f}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int f(x) e^{-i \omega x} dx    \\
$$

On the other hand, it seems to me (please correct me if I am wrong) that the characteristic function of a random variable / probability measure is *always* (or very close to *always*) defined as
$$
\hat{\mu}(\omega) = \int e^{i \omega x} d \mu(x)
$$

All this seems to be confirmed by Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions

So the main difference between analysis / signal processing / electrical engineering on one side and probability on the other is mostly the mius sign.

Even though I do not think there is anything deep underneath this, i.e. just another convention (please confirm), I would be interested in understanding how we ended up with this confusion from a historical perspective.

Maybe there is a reason why the characteristic function was defined without a minus and nobody ever questioned that? Weren't the people who introduced the characteristic function in probability (who was that btw?) looking at analysis books/papers?

Note that my question is admittedly similar to, e.g.,
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2306738/fourier-transform-with-a-different-sign-convention
but I am more insterested in the history.

Comment: cross-posting is generally strongly discouraged, ideally you should close it there and migrate it here, or delete it there first. One reason cross-posting is bad is that it can result in *answer fragmentation* and/or duplicated efforts. An exception is sometimes acceptable after the original question is too old to migrate (60 days I think) but that's not a firm rule. Since 9 << 60 I think your duplicate post situation is considered not good.

Comment: I had [suboptimal results for a history question in Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2395338/284619) It's been bumped a few times over the last four years, but there seems to be not so much interest, so it may be time to either bounty it or ask a similar question here. If I did post something similar here, I'd have to mention the older question in Math SE, and include some of the helpful material in comments as prior research.

Comment: @uhoh I apologize. I will delete it from there. I did not know I could migrate posts.. actually I think I was once told i could *not* migrate (in that case I wanted to migrate from MSE to MO). Maybe the reason was that it s not possible to migrate old questions?

Comment: Ya,from [meta FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/303080) find the lengthy [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/303080) which says "Only questions which are less than 60 days old can be migrated; this rule also applies to moderators."

Answer (score 2):

There is a fourth convention
$$\hat{f}(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{-its}f(t)dt,$$
which is used sometimes.

Comment: Is f(x) missing on the right hand side?

Comment: @M. Farooq: thanks. I corrected.

Answer (score 2):

I agree: the main difference is the minus sign in the exponent.  The other differences are cosmetic.
For a probability measure, we normalize
$$
\hat{\mu}(\omega) = \int e^{i \omega x} d \mu(x)
$$
because $\mu$ has total mass $1$.

For a Fourier series we normalize
$$c_n = \frac{1}{L}\int_0^L e^{-i(2\pi/L)nx}\;dx$$
to make the exponentials into an orthonormal system.

For the Fourier transform, we have neither of these reasons for the normalization.  Which leads to the various conventions.